# A basic doubt on the definition of limit supremum

Tags: real-analysis

I have read two definitions of upper limit for a sequence $\{a_n\}$.

1) Form a monotonically decreasing sequence $\{b_n\}$ such that $\displaystyle b_n=\sup(\operatorname{range}(\{a_n\})-\bigcup_{i=1}^{n-1}a_i$

and take its limit which nothing but the infimum of its range set

2) Supremum of all the subsequential limits of $\{a_n\}$. I know that this supremum is limit of some subsequence of $\{a_n\}$

How to prove that both are equivalent ?

Answer (score 1):

Let's take $b = \lim_{n \to ∞} b_n = \inf_n b_n$ where $b_n = \sup_{k ≥ n} a_k$.

We see that $a_n ≤ b_n$ so for any convergent subsequence $⟨a_{n_k}⟩_k$ we have $\lim_{k \to ∞} a_{n_k} ≤ b$.

On the other hand since $b_n = \sup_{k ≥ n} a_k$ then for any $U$ neighborhood of $b$ there exists $n_0$ such that $a_n ∈ U$ for all $n ≥ n_0$. So it is easy to find convergent subseqence converging to $b$.

In conclusion $b = \max \{x: \text{$x$ is limit of some subseqence of $⟨a_n⟩_n$}\}$.